# Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction' Typescript

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom, react-typescript

As new Version 6 doesn't allow useHistory; I used "useNavigate" instead of useHistory. After taking user input, those input data is supposed to go next page.
While using "History.push" command to pass the data it's showing this error:

**Property 'push' does not exist on type 'NavigateFunction'**

Here is the code:

```
import { useNavigate } from "react-router-dom";

export interface UserData {
  name: string;
  gender: string;
  lang: string;
}
```

```
const history = useNavigate();
```

```
const [UserData, setUserData] = useState<UserData>({
    name: "",
    gender: "Male",
    lang: "React",
  });

  const handleInputChange = (e: React.ChangeEvent<HTMLInputElement>) => {
    const { name, value } = e.target;

    setUserData({ ...UserData, [name]: value });
  };

  const handleSubmit = () => {
    history.push("/exam", UserData);
  };
```

what am I supposed to change and add?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `useNavigate` hook returns a ***function***, not a history object with a `push` method.

[useNavigate](https://reactrouter.com/docs/en/v6/api#usenavigate)

> ```
> declare function useNavigate(): NavigateFunction;
>
> interface NavigateFunction {
>   (
>     to: To,
>     options?: { replace?: boolean; state?: any }
>   ): void;
>   (delta: number): void;
> }
> ```

Rename `history` to `navigate` so there's no future confusion.

```
const navigate = useNavigate();
```

Invoke the `navigate` function and pass the state in the second argument, the optional `options` parameter, under the `state` property.

```
const handleSubmit = () => {
  navigate("/exam", { state: UserData });
};
```